# Creating a Flag within group meeting two criteria within group in SAS

Tags: sas

```
data abc;
length datec $19; 
input id $ param $ datec $ _flg $;
daten = input(datec,is8601dt.);
format daten is8601dt.;
cards;
001 ALT 2013-01-20T09:16 Y
001 AST 2013-01-20T09:16 Y
001 ALP 2013-01-20T09:16 Y
001 TSB 2013-01-21T09:14 Y
002 ALT 2013-02-20T08:16 N
002 AST 2013-02-20T08:16 Y
002 ALP 2013-02-20T08:16 Y
002 TSB 2013-02-21T08:14 Y
003 ALT 2013-01-20T09:16 Y
003 AST 2013-01-20T09:16 Y
003 ALP 2013-01-20T09:16 N
003 TSB 2013-01-21T09:14 N
004 ALT 2013-08-19T09:16 N
004 AST 2013-08-20T09:16 N
004 ALP 2013-08-20T09:16 Y
004 TSB 2013-08-20T11:14 Y
004 ALT 2013-08-21T09:00 Y
005 ALT 2013-08-19T11:16 Y
005 AST 2013-08-20T09:16 Y
005 ALP 2013-08-20T12:16 Y
005 TSB 2013-08-20T11:14 Y
006 ALT 2013-08-19T07:16 Y
006 ALT 2013-08-20T08:16 N
006 AST 2013-08-20T08:16 N
006 ALP 2013-08-20T08:14 Y
006 TSB 2013-08-20T08:16 Y
006 TSB 2013-08-20T08:14 Y
007 ALT 2013-08-19T10:16 Y
007 ALT 2013-08-20T08:16 N
007 AST 2013-08-20T08:16 N
007 ALP 2013-08-20T08:14 Y
007 TSB 2013-08-20T08:16 Y
007 TSB 2013-08-21T08:14 Y
;
run;
```

What I need is to make a flag (_flg2) variable meeting the following criteria.
Within id either ALT or AST should have _FLG as "Y" and ALP and TSB must have _FLG as "Y" within 24hr window. i.e. within 24 hr ALT/AST & ALP & TSB should be "Y".

The final dataset will contain one observation per id. The _flg2 variable will be "Y" for id in (001,002,004,005,007) and missing for remaining id (003,006).

Kindly let me know if this need any further clarification.

Thanks in Advance!

The code I Tried is as follows:

```
proc sort data=abc out=_1;
    by id datec;
run;

data _2;
    set _1 (where=(_FLG = "Y"));
by id datec;
    if _FLG = "Y" then _flg1 = 1;
run;

proc transpose data=_2 out=_3(drop=_NAME_) ;
    by id datec daten;
    var _flg1;
    id param;
run;

data _4 (keep=id alt ast alp tsb daten dtchk dtdif);
    set _3;
    by id datec daten;
    dtdif=dif(daten)/3600;
    if first.id then dtdif=.;
if . lt dtdif lt 24 then dtchk=daten-dtdif*3600;
    format dtchk datetime.;
run;

data _5 (keep=id daten);
    set _4;
    where dtchk ne .;
    by id daten;
    if last.id;
run;

data _6;
    merge   _4(keep=id alt ast alp tsb daten)
            _4(keep=id alt ast alp tsb daten dtchk
            rename=(daten=refdt dtchk=daten alt=alt24 ast=ast24 alp=alp24     tsb=tsb24) where=(daten ne .))
            _5(in=ina);
    by id daten;
    if not ina;
    altf=max(of alt:);
    astf=max(of ast:);
    alpf=max(of alp:);
    tsbf=max(of tsb:);
    if . lt sum(altf, astf) le 2 and sum(alpf, tsbf) = 2 then _FLG2 = "Y";
run;
```

Comment: And the code you've already tried...?

Comment: I've updated the question with the code I'm trying.

Comment: Are you sure that flag2 should be Y for ids 004 and 007? By your own logic I don't think they qualify.

Comment: @user667489 - Yes, 004 and 007 should have flag2 as Y because 
In case of 004, 
ALP (2013-08-20T09:16), TSB (2013-08-20T11:14) and ALT (2013-08-21T09:00) are all Y and falls within 24hr window. 
Same goes for 007, 
ALT (2013-08-19T10:16), ALP (2013-08-20T08:14) and TSB (2013-08-20T08:16) or TSB (2013-08-21T08:14) are all Y and falls within 24hr window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following data step should work:

```
data have;
  input @1 id $3. @5 param $3. @9 date yymmdd10. @20 time time5. @26 FLAG $1.;
  format datetime is8601dt. date yymmdd10. time time5.;
  datetime = dhms(date,hour(time),minute(time),0);
cards;
001 ALT 2013-01-20T09:16 Y
001 AST 2013-01-20T09:16 Y
001 ALP 2013-01-20T09:16 Y
001 TSB 2013-01-21T09:14 Y
002 ALT 2013-02-20T08:16 N
002 AST 2013-02-20T08:16 Y
002 ALP 2013-02-20T08:16 Y
002 TSB 2013-02-21T08:14 Y
003 ALT 2013-01-20T09:16 Y
003 AST 2013-01-20T09:16 Y
003 ALP 2013-01-20T09:16 N
003 TSB 2013-01-21T09:14 N
004 ALT 2013-08-19T09:16 N
004 AST 2013-08-20T09:16 N
004 ALP 2013-08-20T09:16 Y
004 TSB 2013-08-20T11:14 Y
004 ALT 2013-08-21T09:00 Y
005 ALT 2013-08-19T11:16 Y
005 AST 2013-08-20T09:16 Y
005 ALP 2013-08-20T12:16 Y
005 TSB 2013-08-20T11:14 Y
006 ALT 2013-08-19T07:16 Y
006 ALT 2013-08-20T08:16 N
006 AST 2013-08-20T08:16 N
006 ALP 2013-08-20T08:14 Y
006 TSB 2013-08-20T08:16 Y
006 TSB 2013-08-20T08:14 Y
007 ALT 2013-08-19T10:16 Y
007 ALT 2013-08-20T08:16 N
007 AST 2013-08-20T08:16 N
007 ALP 2013-08-20T08:14 Y
007 TSB 2013-08-20T08:16 Y
007 TSB 2013-08-21T08:14 Y
;
run;

proc sort data = have;
  by id date;
run;

data want;
  do until(last.id);
    set have(where = (FLAG = 'Y'));
    by id;
    select(param);
      when('ALT','AST') dt1 = datetime;
      when('ALP')       dt2 = datetime;
      when('TSB')       dt3 = datetime;
    end;
    if intck('dtmin',0,range(of dt1-dt3)) <= 24*60 and nmiss(of dt1-dt3) = 0 then FLAG2 = 'Y';
  end;
  call missing(of dt1-dt3);
  drop dt1-dt3;
run;
```

Provided that your dataset is sorted in date-time order within each id, you only need to compare the most recently encountered date-time for each value of param that has to fall within the same 24-hour window. This avoids a lot of mucking about with transposing, joining on multiple copies of the table etc.

Comment: 004 and 007 should have flag2 as Y because 
In case of 004, 
ALP (2013-08-20T09:16), TSB (2013-08-20T11:14) and ALT (2013-08-21T09:00) are all Y and falls within 24hr window. 
Same goes for 007, 
ALT (2013-08-19T10:16), ALP (2013-08-20T08:14) and TSB (2013-08-20T08:16) or TSB (2013-08-21T08:14) are all Y and falls within 24hr window.

Comment: The code you gave is working for the given data, and it gives desired result (i.e. Y for 001,002,004,005,007), after filtering the have data on flag1="Y". Thanks a ton. But I don't understand your comment of assuming flag2 missing for 004 and 007, as your code gives Y for these id too...

Comment: Sorry about that - there was a bug in the data step I was using to read in the raw data which meant it was reading 11:00 as 01:00 etc. After I fixed that it matches all your test cases.

Comment: Could you please let me know what change in the intck function be incorporated if only the date is collected, and flag2 should be Y for only those ids when ALT/AST & ALP & TSB is "Y" on the same date?

Comment: If you're working with a date variable rather than a datetime variable, try `'day'` instead of `'dtmin'`, or just get rid of `intck` altogether and use `range(of dt1-dt3) = 0` as the first condition on that line.